# Freezes on Dell 7537 with Ubuntu 14.04.1

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, dell, freeze

I installed Ubuntu 14.04.1 on Dell 7537. My laptop has nvidia 750M graphic card.
The problem is that OS the freezes sometimes without any reason.

I installed `nvidia-current` but nothing changes, the OS freezes and touchpad/keyboard don't work, the only thing I can do is power off the PC.

How can I solve? Where can I find some logs?

Comment: @karel I'm not interested on what to do when it freezes. I want to find the reason why it freezes, and then solve it. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to switch to a VT (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) and back (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>)?

Recently, I installed Ubuntu 14.04.1 with proprietary NVidia 340.29 drivers on the same laptop and have experienced the same issue. A VT switch helped me.
Also it looks like it is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/xorg-server/+bug/1220426)

Comment: I tried switching to the nouveau drivers and it stopeed freezing, but now I have some crashes. Hope they will solve the bug.